# Databricks multiselect dropdown select/Deselect all values

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, multi-select

We are using multiselect dropdown in databricks, based on the selection in the multiselect widget the query results the graphical data. Currently we can select or unselect the options one by one individually but we wanted to have a way to select and unselect all the options from widget.

Code for the multiselect widget :

```
dbutils.widgets.multiselect("channel", "Temp", [str(x) for x in channel])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible with a multiselect widget. My only suggestion is you use some options in the widgets that are implemented with the desired behavior when you read in the values from the widget.

e.g. create the widget with addtional "All" and "None" options

```
channel = ["Foo", "Bar", "Temp"]
dbutils.widgets.multiselect("channel", "Temp", [str(x) for x in channel] + ["None",  "All"])
```

One possible implementation is that when "None" is selected that overrides all other selections. when "All" is selected that overrides all other selections except "None".

```
out = dbutils.widgets.get("channel").split(",")

if "None" in out:
  channel_out = ['']
elif "All" in out:
  channel_out = channel
else:
  channel_out = out
```

That won't look as nice as what you want in the UI, but it will give you an easy way of toggling between running for a group of channels and then either all or none.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! We can use it this way but like you said it wont look nice on UI. Is it possible that we can use JQuery, try to create one in HTML then read and use the selected values in the next cells.

Comment: Using the mentioned approach with widget, If we opt 'All' then is there a way that from notebook cell we show all the other values selected automatically.